# Command to unzip a specific folder using 7zip

Tags: java, windows, 7zip

I am working with windows to be more specific, I am invoking the `cmd` Command from java program using process and `getRuntime().exec()`. I tried options like `-r` but its not working. I tried the code line

```
Process proc = prog.exec(System.getenv("ProgramFiles").concat("\\7-Zip\\7z x " + "\""+inputZIPFile+"\""+ " -o"+outputFolder+"SpecificFolder\\* -r"));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exaclty is not working. Show the error/stack trace. May be you want to use Apache Commons Exec (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) to make your live easier.

Comment: No errors are detected.But the specific folder which i want to extract is getting concatenated with the output folder and the whole zip gets extracted over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by using `ProcessBuilder` instead.  It handles parameters with spaces better and allows you do things like redirect the output stream and specify the starting directory for the command...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
        System.getenv("ProgramFiles") + "/7-Zip/7z.exe",
            "x",
            inputZIPFile,
            "-o" + outputFolder+"/SpecificFolder",
            "-r"
    );
    pb.redirectError();
    try {
        Process p = pb.start();
        new Thread(new InputConsumer(p.getInputStream())).start();
        System.out.println("Exited with: " + p.waitFor());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static  class InputConsumer implements Runnable {
    private InputStream is;

    public InputConsumer(InputStream is) {
        this.is = is;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            int value = -1;
            while ((value = is.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) value);
            }
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

You might also want to consider [Apache Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/) which provides read support for 7zip

Comment: hie am getting    `exited with 2`

Comment: It's not helpful, but apparently, 2 is fatal error :P

Comment: Have you tested the command on the command line to make sure it works?

Comment: just checked its not working..do u have any idea about the cmd to extract a specific folder from a zip..??

Comment: Well the command I my example code worked for me, tested it locally

Comment: Does it extract only the "specifiedfolder" from the inputZIPFile?

Comment: `7z x " + input +"  -o" + output +" *\SpecificFolder\*.*`, basically, the last parameter is the file(s) to be extracted...

Comment: Made a small change in your code and it worked    `new ProcessBuilder(System.getenv("ProgramFiles") + "/7-Zip/7z.exe","x",inputZIPFile,"-o" + outputFolder,"specifiedFolder/*","-r");` but it is not terminating i have to force stop it

Comment: In my first post, I forget to `start` the consumer thread, `new Thread(new InputConsumer(p.getInputStream())).start();`...are you using this updated code?

Comment: Yeah, took me a few minutes to get that to :P

Answer (score 0):

Why not unzip using java? From [Compressing and Decompressing Data Using Java APIs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/compress-1565076.html):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;

public class UnZip {
   final int BUFFER = 2048;
   public static void main (String argv[]) {
      try {
         BufferedOutputStream dest = null;
         FileInputStream fis = new 
       FileInputStream(argv[0]);
         ZipInputStream zis = new 
       ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));
         ZipEntry entry;
         while((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Extracting: " +entry);
            int count;
            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
            // write the files to the disk
            FileOutputStream fos = new 
          FileOutputStream(entry.getName());
            dest = new 
              BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER);
            while ((count = zis.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) 
              != -1) {
               dest.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            dest.flush();
            dest.close();
         }
         zis.close();
      } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Because, unless it's an actual zip file, this won't work, just saying ;)