# How to run process builder command as thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, imagemagick, image-conversion

I need to do the image conversion inside a folder using process builder with the help of image magick tool. I need to delete the original files after conversion but when i used wait for it takes long time to complete. i used the following code

```
          for (int h = 0; h < convimagefolder.size(); h++) {
            /* CMYK conversion for jpg and tiff and also .psd conversion*/
            destpathfinalconvs = new File(tempdir + "/" + convimagefolder.get(h));

            //  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "CMYK jpg conversion - folder assign");
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("mogrify", "-colorspace", "RGB", destpathfinalconvs.toString() + "\\" + "*.jpg");
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            try {
                Process p = pb.start();
                System.out.println("CMYK to RGB jpg done for "+convimagefolder.get(h));
//                try {
//                    p.waitFor();
//                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
//                    Logger.getLogger(DefineTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DefineTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            //  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "tif conversion - folder assign");
            ProcessBuilder pb1 = new ProcessBuilder("mogrify", "-colorspace", "RGB", destpathfinalconvs.toString() + "\\" + "*.tif");
            pb1.redirectErrorStream(true);
            try {
                Process p1 = pb1.start();
                System.out.println("cmyk tif to rgb done " + convimagefolder.get(h));
//                try {
//                    p1.waitFor();
//                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
//                    Logger.getLogger(DefineTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DefineTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            //  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "psd conversion - folder assign");
            ProcessBuilder pb2 = new ProcessBuilder("mogrify", "-format", "jpg", destpathfinalconvs.toString() + "\\" + "*.psd[0]");
            pb2.redirectErrorStream(true);
            try {
                Process p2 = pb2.start();
                System.out.println("psd to jpg done" + convimagefolder.get(h));
//                try {
//                    p2.waitFor();
//                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
//                    Logger.getLogger(DefineTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DefineTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            /* CMYK conversion for jpg and tiff and also .psd conversion*/


            /* tif to jpg conversion*/
            ProcessBuilder pb3 = new ProcessBuilder("mogrify", "-format", "jpg", destpathfinalconvs.toString() + "\\" + "*.tif");
            pb3.redirectErrorStream(true);
            try {
                Process p3 = pb3.start();
//                try {
//                    p3.waitFor();
//                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
//                    Logger.getLogger(DefineTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//                }
                System.out.println(".tif to jpg done successfully"+ convimagefolder.get(h));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DefineTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in tif to jpg conversion " + ex.toString());

            }


            /* pdf to jpg*/
            ProcessBuilder pb4 = new ProcessBuilder("mogrify", "-format", "jpg", destpathfinalconvs.toString() + "\\" + "*.pdf");
            pb4.redirectErrorStream(true);
            try {
                Process p4 = pb4.start();
//                try {
//                    p4.waitFor();
//                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
//                    Logger.getLogger(DefineTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//                }
                System.out.println(".pdf to jpg done successfully"+ convimagefolder.get(h));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DefineTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in tif to jpg conversion " + ex.toString());

            }


            /* image size reduction*/
            ProcessBuilder pb5 = new ProcessBuilder("mogrify", "-strip", "-quality", "50%", destpathfinalconvs.toString() + "\\" + "*.jpg");
            //   ProcessBuilder pb5 = new ProcessBuilder("mogrify", "-path ", destinationpath.toString(), "-strip", "-quality", "50%",  destinationpath.toString() + "\\" + "*.jpg");
            pb5.redirectErrorStream(true);
            try {
                Process p5 = pb5.start();
//                try {
//                    p5.waitFor();
//                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
//                    Logger.getLogger(DefineTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//                }
                System.out.println("image conversion done successfully"+ convimagefolder.get(h));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DefineTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in jpg compression " + ex.toString());
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Image compression and conversion done using Image Magick");
```

Is it possible to do this via thread. Please suggest any idea to cut short the time for conversion

Comment: Yes, it's possible, it won't make it any faster and you would still need to either run the entire block in a `Thread` or as a series of chained tasks...What is it you are hoping to improve?

Comment: After this conversion am deleting the files but when the process not completed none of the files are added into my arraylist to delete

Comment: i need to reduce the conversion time. Here it is taking 2-4 minutes.I need to reduce this time

Comment: The best you can hope for, is interleaving the execution of the process so that more than one process can run at a time, this might actually increase the conversion time, as they will no be competing for machine resources...

Answer (score 3):

I would take a look at [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html), which would allow you to pool a series of tasks and have them executed within one or more threads automatically...

For example...

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(7);

for (int h = 0; h < convimagefolder.size(); h++) {

    /* CMYK conversion for jpg and tiff and also .psd conversion*/
    destpathfinalconvs = new File(tempdir + "/" + convimagefolder.get(h));

    service.submit(new ProcessTask(
            "CMYK to RGB jpg done for " + convimagefolder.get(h),
            new String[]{
                "mogrify", "-colorspace", "RGB", destpathfinalconvs.toString() + "\\" + "*.jpg"}
    ));
    service.submit(new ProcessTask(
            "CMYK to RGB jpg done for " + convimagefolder.get(h),
            new String[]{
                "mogrify", "-colorspace", "RGB", destpathfinalconvs.toString() + "\\" + "*.jpg"}
    ));
    service.submit(new ProcessTask(
            "cmyk tif to rgb done " + convimagefolder.get(h),
            new String[]{
                "mogrify", "-colorspace", "RGB", destpathfinalconvs.toString() + "\\" + "*.tif"}
    ));
    service.submit(new ProcessTask(
            "psd to jpg done" + convimagefolder.get(h),
            new String[]{
                "mogrify", "-format", "jpg", destpathfinalconvs.toString() + "\\" + "*.psd[0]"}
    ));
    service.submit(new ProcessTask(
            ".tif to jpg done successfully" + convimagefolder.get(h),
            new String[]{
                "mogrify", "-format", "jpg", destpathfinalconvs.toString() + "\\" + "*.tif"
            }
    ));
    service.submit(new ProcessTask(
            ".pdf to jpg done successfully" + convimagefolder.get(h),
            new String[]{
                "mogrify", "-format", "jpg", destpathfinalconvs.toString() + "\\" + "*.pdf"
            }
    ));
    service.submit(new ProcessTask(
            "image conversion done successfully" + convimagefolder.get(h),
            new String[]{
                "mogrify", "-strip", "-quality", "50%", destpathfinalconvs.toString() + "\\" + "*.jpg"}
    ));
}
```

And the actually `Callable` task...

```
public class ProcessTask implements Callable<Integer> {

    private String cmds[];
    private String name;

    public ProcessTask(String name, String[] cmds) {
        this.cmds = cmds;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Started " + name);
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmds);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p5 = pb.start();
        p5.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Completed " + name);
        return p5.exitValue();
    }

}
```

Now, if you wanted to wait till all the tasks have completed and inspect their states (see who completed successfully and who failed), you could add all the `Callable`s to a `List` and use `ExecutorService#invokeAll(List)`, which will block until all the `Callable`s in the `List` have completed.  You can then iterate through the returned `List` and see if any of the `Callable`s have failed (call `Callable#get` which will return the value the `Callable` returned or throw the `Exception` that the `Callable` raised...)

Another approach might be to, instead of executing the processes within individual `Callable`s, create a `Callable` which took the reference of the `File`, add these to the `ExecutorService` and execute each step within the `Callable`, waiting for each to complete, using the referenced `File`...

This way, when you get to the end, you could just delete the file.  This would allow you to process each file in parallel...

Comment: i tried this it is not converting images and similarly not able to delete files but it is faster

Comment: One thing you're not doing, is process the output from the underlying `Process`, which could be reporting errors or problems, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523997/command-to-unzip-a-specific-folder-using-7zip/24524170#24524170). You should, also, not delete the file until you are sure that all the required processing is complete...